# Как построить график в unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо построить график, а также, чтобы пользователь мог редактировать его. Вносить новые данные.

В интернете нашёл интересный платный вариант из Asset Store - Smart Chart (примерно такой мне нужен). Но сомневаюсь, что его сможет редактировать пользователь.

Comment: Тебе нужно, что бы пользователь вводил свои точки или прямо с графика удалял?

Comment: Что-бы пользователь вводил свои точки

Comment: как вариант - рендер в текстуру при помощи шейдера, и эту текстуру показывать

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlxuHo5O4UU

Собственно ищем видео на YT (пример: "unity3d graph")
Из видео понятно что график строится с помощью системы частиц, соответственно через скрипт задаете переменные Х и У параметрам системы частиц и получаете визуализацию без использования сторонних плагинов

Comment: Можете объяснить как из ситемы частиц сделать график?

Answer (score 0):

Пользователь сможет вводить свои точки. 
Для это вам необходимо сделать поля ввода и кнопку, по которой будут вызываться функция из скрипта.

В самом скрипте вам необходима будет публичная переменная с типом классом таблицы.

У них это скорее всего ChartDataPusher. Но я могу ошибаться. В этом классе будут методы, с помощью которых вы сможете добавить свои точки.

Answer (score 0):

Вот видео сделали на русском с полным объяснением как сделать график - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTKivkiYbK8&t=21s

В этом видео автор сначала создаёт точки на графике с помощью

```
GameObject circleGameObject = CreateCircle(new Vector2(xPosition, yPosition))
```

привязывает к ним палочки

```
GameObject gameObject = new GameObject("dotConnection", typeof(Image));
```

а дальше использует библиотеку codemonkey, одного известного иностранного ютюбера, с помощью которой он соединяет точки на графике

```
rectTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0,UtilsClass.GetAngleFromVectorFloat(dir));
```

Comment: что такое dotConnection? почему typeof Image? Как эти три строки связаны с построением графика, о котором идет речь в вопросе?